# Usecases for GCC Warning Options -Wno-sign-compare, -Wno-type-limits and -Wno-logical-op

Tags: warnings, mingw, gcc-warning

I was deciding the compiler settings for my project that is built using MinGW. It appears that GCC has a really huge set of options for controlling the warnings.

But what I did not understand is why an option is provided to disable some warnings that are critical and hardly cause any nuisance.

**-Wno-sign-compare:** Disables the warning that warns when a comparison between signed and unsigned values could produce an incorrect result when the signed value is converted to
unsigned.

**-Wno-type-limits:** Disables the warning that warns if a comparison is always true or always false due to the limited range of the data type, but does not warn for constant expressions

**-Wno-logical-op:** Disables the warning that warns suspicious uses of logical operators in expressions. This includes using logical operators in contexts where a bit-wise operator is likely to be expected

For me these are really valid warnings and I cannot think of a usecase where they can be disabled. I would be glad if I could get some usecases where such warnings are not serious and fixing them making code changes is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Since a few days ago, I would have fully agreed. However, at least for the -Wno-type-limits I know a use case now:

If you check the value of an enum to be really part of the valid range, sometimes constructs like this occur:

```
  /* Check if the Input Error is within range */
  if ((ErrorId >= (CS_ErrHdl_ErrorId_t)0) && (ErrorId < CS_ErrHdl_ErrId_EndOfList))
  {
    ...
  }
```

Where `CS_ErrHdl_ErrorId_t` is an enum type and `ErrorId` is of that enum type.

As a standard enum (without explicit values given) always starts with 0, there is always the warning:

comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]

In that particular case it helps to switch off that warning as it pollutes all the compiler output.

(Of course one could argue whether this comparison is useful. However, it's used frequently.)

Cheers,
Felix

Answer (score 0):

I have an environment (ARM mbed OS) where `clock_t` is unsigned. But the C standard library says that `clock()` is supposed to return -1 on failure, so I have a check in then nature of: `if(clock() < 0)`. This throws -Wtype-limits since `clock()` can't return a negative integer.

It might be easy enough for me to change my code to match the non-conforming environment, but since there are no negative side effects, I would rather write correct portable code and disable the warning in this environment.